# Simulate controller action with python

Tags: python, controller, xbox

I'm working on a Python project and I'm hurting a problem. I have a Xbox one controller connected to my PC and I'm wondering if It's possible to simulate movement on it (like joystick deplacement) using python.
I tried using `vgamepad` but It doesn't worked (here is what I made if it can help).

```py
left_thumb_x = 1  # Exemple simple, à ajuster selon vos besoins
left_thumb_y = 0  # Vous pouvez ajuster cela en fonction de vos besoins

gamepad.left_joystick(x_value=left_thumb_x, y_value=left_thumb_y)
gamepd.press_button(button=vg.XUSB_BUTTON.XUSB_GAMEPAD_A)
```

Do someone have any idea on how could I achieve that ?